# Prove that square of even integer is even.

Tags: proof-verification

Is my proof correct?

Suppose $n=2m$
  is an even integer. Since $n=2m$
 , then $n^{2}=(2m)^{2}$

$n^{2}$   =   $(2m)^{2}$
=   $4m^{2}$

=$2(2m^{2)}$

Since $(2m^{2})$
  is an integer and $2(2m^{2})$
  is in the form $2m$
 , we have proven that the square of an even integer is even.

Comment: Yes, your proof looks fine.

Comment: Yep.${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, that is pretty much it. Good job.

Comment: Who downvotes a perfectly good answer?

Comment: And I even made the answer CW to not gain unfair rep! :P